# Difference of the floor of a product and the product of floors

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there any way the following can be simplified?

$$\lfloor f(x)\cdot g(x) \rfloor - \lfloor f(x) \rfloor  \cdot \lfloor g(x) \rfloor$$

Comment: In what way is this not simple?

Comment: This might be at it's most simplified form, I'm not sure, I just feel like it may be able to be simplified further, or put in terms of another function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that your values $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are outputs of functions doesn't affect anything unless there is something special about the range of the functions you haven't told us. Therefore, you want another way to write $\lfloor ab\rfloor-\lfloor a\rfloor\lfloor b\rfloor$.

Using the relatively common notation $\{x\}$ for the "fractional part" of $x$, given by $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, we can write the following:
$$\lfloor ab\rfloor-\lfloor a\rfloor\lfloor b\rfloor$$
$$=\left\lfloor (\lfloor a\rfloor+\{a\})(\lfloor b\rfloor+\{b\})\right\rfloor-\lfloor a\rfloor\lfloor b\rfloor$$
$$=\left\lfloor \lfloor a\rfloor\lfloor b\rfloor+\{a\}\lfloor b\rfloor+\{b\}\lfloor a\rfloor+\{a\}\{b\}\right\rfloor-\lfloor a\rfloor\lfloor b\rfloor$$
$$=\left\lfloor \{a\}\lfloor b\rfloor+\{b\}\lfloor a\rfloor+\{a\}\{b\}\right\rfloor\text{ (1)}$$
$$=\left\lfloor \{a\}\lfloor b\rfloor+\{b\}\left(\lfloor a\rfloor+\{a\}\right)\right\rfloor$$
$$=\left\lfloor \{a\}\lfloor b\rfloor+a\{b\}\right\rfloor$$

It may be tempting to discard the term $\{a\}\{b\}<1$ from (1), but that could be enough to change which integer the desired floor is.

Comment: Thank you! I've got a quick follow-up question though, what would it look like if $a=b$?

Comment: @diligar then you could factor out $\{a\} $ from the final expression to get $\lfloor \{a\} (a+\lfloor a\rfloor)\rfloor $, which you could write a few different ways, like with $a+\lfloor a\rfloor=2a-\{a\}$.

Comment: If a = b then the question would become floor(a)^2 - floor(a^2). I don't think that is any more reducable. Honestly this equation is pretty clunky as is. I'd stick with the unreduced form. I've found that putting floor within floor creates unneccesary messiness when it is avoidable. It is better to not put piecewise in piecewise. That would actually be a good rule of thumb in reducing. So if anything, this went backwards.

Comment: @thegreatduck, I basically agree. I just gave another form because that's what the op seemed to be asking for. Which one is best for their purposes is something they'll have to decide.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's
$$
    \left\lfloor \lfloor f(x) \rfloor ( g(x) - \lfloor g(x) \rfloor ) + g(x) ( f(x) - \lfloor f(x) \rfloor )  \right\rfloor
$$

Maybe you consider that simpler, perhaps so if write $\mathrm{frac}(x)$ for the fractional part of $x$ ($0 \leq \mathrm{frac}(x) < 1$): 
$$
    \left\lfloor \lfloor f(x) \rfloor \mathrm{frac}(g(x)) + g(x) \mathrm{frac}(f(x)) \right\rfloor
$$

You can also swap $f$ and $g$.

What were you hoping for?